# How to use .find command in webscraping

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My code is supposed to pull data from a website using the beautifulsoup library, but keeps on returning none as the output when I try to use it.

my code

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import requests
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + stock_code + '?p=' + stock_code
r = requests.get(url)
web_content = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
#texts = web_content_div(web_content, 'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px) W(100%)')
section = web_content.find('fin-streamer')
display(section)
```

is trying to pull a number from yahoo finance shown here
[image]

it keeps returning none, frankly this is probably just a formatting issue, but it's 1 and I want to go to sleep. Any advice on how to actually pull what I want from the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using your original `requests.get` call won't return the same result you get from the browser due to being blocked by Yahoo Finance. To workaround it, you should add the parameter `headers` with user-agent specified (`headers={'USER-AGENT': "Mozilla/5.0"}`). Afterwards, if you print out the response text content, you should see there are multiple `fin-streamer` tags in the html text

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import requests
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

stock_code = 'AAPL'
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + stock_code + '?p=' + stock_code
r = requests.get(url, headers={'USER-AGENT': "Mozilla/5.0"})
web_content = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')t.find('fin-streamer')
print(section)
```